# How to print a range of values for i loc

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to print a range of values say from 42580 to 42599, how would one do that? I can only print a specific row, i.e. below

#print(df.loc[42588])

Comment: `df.iloc[42580:42599]` or `df.iloc[42580:42599+1]` to include the endpoint